# "Assertion failure" while adding Socialize Action Bar

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios5

I am trying to add the Socialize Action Bar to my IOS app. I have done most of the steps as listed on
http://socialize.github.com/socialize-sdk-ios/action_bar.html

While running the app, I get the error:

> Assertion failure in -[SocializeConfiguration initWithWithConfigurationPath:]

If I comment the line

```
self.actionBar = [SocializeActionBar actionBarWithKey:@"http://www.example.com/object/1234" presentModalInController:self];
```

I do not get the error, but I do not see the Socialize Action Bar as well.

So I think the issue is while setting the above line. I am not sure what the URL should be exactly?

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972432/add-multiple-entity-with-socializeactionbar#comment12742159_9972432

Comment: you need set proper and correct url for this not any dummy otherwise you will get same error...