# Add Multiple Entity with SocializeActionBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios5

Hello i am using SocializeActionBar for my app there i have multiple links.

I am creating it like this

```
self.actionBar = [SocializeActionBar actionBarWithKey:@"http://www.logisticinfotech.com/extra/acc_ident.mp3" name:@"acc_ident" presentModalInController:self];

[self.view addSubview:self.actionBar.view];
```

my Question is that i want to change url but not want to create new object of SocializeActionBar.

because i have lots more than 100 images so creating new object for every images is not good idea as point of memory for iphone.

Thanks in Advance for any kind of help and Suggetions...

Comment: You can always set an object to `nil` and `alloc`ate new blocks for memory efficiency

Comment: This will create another problem i.e increase view counts for same page when we create new object...

Comment: When you're setting it to `nil`, you can remove it from subview simultaneously...

Comment: i am discussing for this in form if i got any reply then i will surely post it here for reference to others...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You can't change url of actionbar without allocating it again.

you have to use your custom logic for what you want.